# Interior Left Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using this package.
http://carbondesignsystem.com/components/interior-left-nav/code

Do you have any idea to fix this problem?
I want "Nav" to be closed on blur event.

My Question is as below.

[image: Question]

**My Code.**

```html
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Interior Left Navigation" data-interior-left-nav class="bx--interior-left-nav bx--interior-left-nav--collapseable">
  <ul role="menubar" class="left-nav-list" data-interior-left-nav-list aria-hidden="false">
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="left-nav-list__item" data-interior-left-nav-item>
      <a class="left-nav-list__item-link">
        Example Item 1
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bx--interior-left-nav-collapse" data-interior-left-nav-collapse>
    <a class="bx--interior-left-nav-collapse__link" href="#">
      <svg class="bx--interior-left-nav-collapse__arrow" width="8" height="12" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M7.5 10.6L2.8 6l4.7-4.6L6.1 0 0 6l6.1 6z"></path>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: yes. I'm using jQuery & angularJS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use `jQuery mouseout`, `blur` or `mouseleave` method.

```
$('nav[role="navigation"]').mouseleave(function(){ 
  // call toggleLeftNav() method
  //toggleLeftNav();
  $('.bx--interior-left-nav-collapse').click();
});
```

**Reference Document:**

- jQuery [mouseout](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)
- jQuery [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- jQuery [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Hope this will help you.

If you are using `angularJS`, then use `ng-mouseleave="toggleLeftNav()"` in the `nav` tag.

Reference Document: [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) or [ng-mouseleave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave)

Comment: the event fired but message below showed up

`Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleLeftNav is not defined`

Comment: @KyogoMochida You need to use `ng-mouseleave="toggleLeftNav()"` in the `nav` tag.  **Reference Doc:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

Comment: > You need to use ng-mouseleave="toggleLeftNav()"....
@Shiladitya thanks but same error again

Comment: @KyogoMochida I've updated the jQuery answer, have a look. I'm trying to trigger a click on mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Shiladitya's advice, I got solution.
I connect "mouseleave" event to "click" close icon event and worked.

```
    $('nav[role="navigation"]').mouseleave(function(){ 
    var a = document.getElementById("closeHamburgerMenu");
    function triggerEvent(element, event) {
           if (document.createEvent) {
               // not IE
               var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
               evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type, bubbling, cancelable
               return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
           } else {
               // IE
               var evt = document.createEventObject();
               return element.fireEvent("on"+event, evt)
           }
        }
    triggerEvent(a, 'click');
    });
```